# Tool Dialogs appear blank in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing

All of a sudden my Toolbox in ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop has stopped working.

Last week i was using clip tool but the toolbox window was blank, i tried other tools but it shows the same blank window.

[image]